# Django Compressor and Deployment

Tags: css, django, url, deployment, compression

Some things about [Django Compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor) are not clear to me. 
1) Should I use it only on development environment? If not, does it mean that it will compress and aggregate static js/css files at every request even on the production environment? 
2) Is it possible to change the internal css url to images? I mean, for example:

```
body{
    background: #2b2925 url('http://localhost:8000/static/img/MyBG.png');
}
```

This, of course will not work on prod environment. Should I use `compressor` to change this url on the production server or should I use another approach? E.g. Parsing and substituting with a `Fabric` script during the deployment?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to be serving files locally that would be served by the staticfiles app on an absolute URL. You can simply use a relative path to the file. That will solve your issue of needing to re-write paths for local versus production.

So for example use:

```
body {
    background: #2b2925 url('../img/MyBG.png');
}
```

The relative path may be different given your directory structure.

Compressor will only compress files whose mtimes are different, meaning that unless the files have changed, it won't re-compress the files on every request.

Comment: Consider that I will always edit my files locally (never remotely) and then I will push them to the remote server.
If I edit and compress the files locally then this means I will deploy them in production already compressed. So, do I need (and why) the compressor app to run also in production?

Comment: If you're going to pre-compress them, then no, you don't need to run it in production. I do the same thing with Less files. I pre-compile them locally, then only deploy minified CSS, which in, turn, gets compressed by compressor.